# What is the increasing order in which we can arrange the sorting algorithms on the basis of number of swap operations?

Tags: algorithm

I am having a bit problem in actually finding out what must be the correct order in which the sorting algorithms must be arranged so as to minimize the no of swap operations .

Selection sort has minimum no of swap operations , and Insertion sort and bubble sort have nearly equal no of swap operations but I am unable to analyze which algorithm has least between them .Also I am unable to fix the correct position in which Merge sort and Heap sort must be placed among these sorting algorithms so as to maintain a proper ascending order in terms of number of swap operations .

Comment: Don't judge sort algorithms by number of swaps, use time complexity. If your objects are expensive to copy, use indirect sort or smart pointers.

Comment: @imreal What if writing into the memory is significantly slower than reading?

Comment: How much faster is reading it in the architecture you're working on? Are you writing to disk? How big is the collection you're ordering?